# Webpack v5 does not generate valid ES3 code for IE8 or WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use webpack v5.74.0 with babel-loader 8.2.5 to transpile and pack Javascript code that must be compatible with Microsofts WebBrowser control (i.e IE 8 / ES3 standard).
Specifically, the WebBrowser control will throw and "Expected identifier" error when encountering JS code where a method name is also a JS keyword, e.g. Set.delete().

Here is a small test case:

**project structure**

```
$ ls -l -R --hide=node_modules
.:
total 266
drwxr-xr-x 1 demo.user 197121      0 Oct 21 17:32 dist/
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo.user 197121 265954 Oct 21 16:56 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo.user 197121    393 Oct 21 18:09 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 1 demo.user 197121      0 Oct 21 16:06 src/
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo.user 197121    917 Oct 21 17:45 webpack.prod.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo.user 197121    145 Oct 21 17:16 xxxbabel.config.json

./dist:
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo.user 197121 94 Oct 21 17:33 main.js

./src:
total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 demo.user 197121 94 Oct 21 17:46 main.js
```

**package.json:**

```js
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config=webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.prod.js:**

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.js"
  },
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    environment: {
      arrowFunction: false  // prevent top level arrow IIFE on Webpack 5
    },
    clean: true   // clean output dir before each build
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,  // transpile JS for older browsers
        exclude: /node_modules/,  // don't mess with node_modules
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            "presets": [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env', {
                  targets: {
                    "ie": "8"   // target for IE 8 ES3 for WebBrowser control
                  },
                  debug: true
                }
              ]
            ],  // let's us use latest JS features
            //"plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals" ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Input code:
**src/main.js**

Here I use as example the `delete` method of the Set object, see
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```js
var d = new Set("a", "b", "c");
d["delete"]("a");
console.log("Set has a? "+d.has("a"));
```

Calling webpack using

> `npm run build`

```
$ npm run build

> webpack-test@1.0.0 build
> webpack --config=webpack.prod.js

@babel/preset-env: `DEBUG` option

Using targets:
{
  "ie": "8"
}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
  proposal-class-static-block { ie }
  proposal-private-property-in-object { ie }
  proposal-class-properties { ie }
  proposal-private-methods { ie }
  proposal-numeric-separator { ie }
  proposal-logical-assignment-operators { ie }
  proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator { ie }
  proposal-optional-chaining { ie }
  proposal-json-strings { ie }
  proposal-optional-catch-binding { ie }
  transform-parameters { ie }
  proposal-async-generator-functions { ie }
  proposal-object-rest-spread { ie }
  transform-dotall-regex { ie }
  proposal-unicode-property-regex { ie }
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex { ie }
  transform-async-to-generator { ie }
  transform-exponentiation-operator { ie }
  transform-template-literals { ie }
  transform-literals { ie }
  transform-function-name { ie }
  transform-arrow-functions { ie }
  transform-block-scoped-functions { ie < 11 }
  transform-classes { ie }
  transform-object-super { ie }
  transform-shorthand-properties { ie }
  transform-duplicate-keys { ie }
  transform-computed-properties { ie }
  transform-for-of { ie }
  transform-sticky-regex { ie }
  transform-unicode-escapes { ie }
  transform-unicode-regex { ie }
  transform-spread { ie }
  transform-destructuring { ie }
  transform-block-scoping { ie }
  transform-typeof-symbol { ie }
  transform-new-target { ie }
  transform-regenerator { ie }
  transform-member-expression-literals { ie < 9 }
  transform-property-literals { ie < 9 }
  transform-reserved-words { ie < 9 }
  proposal-export-namespace-from { ie }
  syntax-dynamic-import
  syntax-top-level-await

Using polyfills: No polyfills were added, since the `useBuiltIns` option was not set.
asset main.js 94 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
./src/main.js 90 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.74.0 compiled successfully in 1940 ms
```

webpack / babel output:
**dist/main.js:**

```js
!function(){var a=new Set("a","b","c");a.delete("a"),console.log("Set has a? "+a.has("a"))}();
```

Note the call `a.delete()` which is invalid for IE8. It will result in the above mentioned "Expected identifier" error message.

**Excpected output**
Expected output would be same as input, i.e. the call to the delete method should read `a["delete"]()`.

I have tried to check with babel alone using their REPL page, where the codes is transpiled correctly:
https://babel.dev/repl#?browsers=ie%208&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=G4QwTgBAJhC8EDsCmB3CBlJAXAFAIhDwBoI8AjY0gYzwEoBuAKCgDookAbbJfQhoA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.19.6&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D

Therefore I suppose either the configuration file is incorrect or the webpack/babel-loader configuration is not passed properly to babel. I would appreciate any help that resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the solution. Apparently it's not a babel issue but the minification that happens afterwards. Terser (the minifier) messes up the code. I could find the correct option to prevent terser from replacing the property access with dot notation, documented here:
https://github.com/terser/terser#compress-options

First we need to include the terser plugin in webpack.prod.js:

```
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
```

and then append a terser configuration after the 'module' config:

```
optimization: {
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
    terserOptions: {
        compress: { properties: false },
        mangle: false,
    },
  })],
}
```

Complete webpack.prod.js:

```js
const path = require("path");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.js"
  },
  mode: "production",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    environment: {
      arrowFunction: false  // prevent top level arrow IIFE on Webpack 5
    },
    clean: true   // clean output dir before each build
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,  // transpile JS for older browsers
        exclude: /node_modules/,  // don't mess with node_modules
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            "presets": [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env', {
                  targets: {
                    "ie": "8"   // target for IE 8 ES3 for WebBrowser control
                  },
                  debug: true
                }
              ]
            ],  // let's us use latest JS features
            //"plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-transform-member-expression-literals" ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        compress: { properties: false }, // important: don't rewrite property access using the dot notation, e.g. foo["bar"] → foo.bar
        mangle: false,
      },
    })],
  }
}
```

Output file dist/main.js is then as expected:

```
$ cat dist/main.js
!function(){var d=new Set("a","b","c");d["delete"]("a"),console.log("Set has a? "+d.has("a"))}();
```